# OrientDB keeps locking records indefinitely

Tags: orientdb

I'm running OrientDB (community edition 2.2.9) in distributed mode with multiple nodes.

After a couple of minutes, I start getting the following error on my queries:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.task.ODistributedRecordLockedException: Timeout (1500ms) on acquiring lock on record #1010:2651. It is locked by request 3.1000 DB name="MyDatabase"
```

The query in this instance looks like this:

```
UPDATE #1010:2651 SET name='foo';
```

The record remains locked and I can't run the query until I restart the database.

If I don't run the server in distributed mode, I don't get this error so it must have something to do with running it in distributed mode.

Here is my default-distributed-db-config.json

```
{
  "autoDeploy": true,
  "readQuorum": 1,
  "writeQuorum": 1,
  "executionMode": "asynchronous",
  "readYourWrites": true,
  "servers": {
    "*": "master"
  },
  "clusters": {
    "internal": {
    },
    "*": {
     "servers": ["<NEW_NODE>"]
    }
  }
}
```

I was using the following configuration in my orientdb-server-config.xml:

```
    ....
    <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin">
        <parameters>
            ....
            <parameter value="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.conflict.ODefaultReplicationConflictResolver" name="conflict.resolver.impl"/>
            ....
        </parameters>
    </handler>
   ...
```

By removing the "**ODefaultReplicationConflictResolver**" paramter from the config, the locking issue happens less frequently.

Why are the records locking up like this and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `asynchronous` execution mode may cause this problem. See: [Asynchronous replication mode](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Distributed-Configuration.html#asynchronous-replication-mode).

You can try changing execution mode or try adding a retry into your query. Using Java: it is possible to catch events of command during asynchronous replication, thanks to the following method of OCommandSQL:

- `onAsyncReplicationOk()`, to catch the event when the asynchronous replication succeed
- `onAsyncReplicationError()`, to catch the event when the asynchronous replication returns error

Example retrying up to 3 times in case of concurrent modification exception on creation of edges:

```
g.command( new OCommandSQL("create edge Own from (select from User) to (select from Post)")
 .onAsyncReplicationError(new OAsyncReplicationError() {
  @Override
  public ACTION onAsyncReplicationError(Throwable iException, int iRetry) {
    System.err.println("Error, retrying...");
    return iException instanceof ONeedRetryException && iRetry<=3 ? ACTION.RETRY : ACTION.IGNORE;
  }
})
 .onAsyncReplicationOk(new OAsyncReplicationOk() {
   System.out.println("OK");
 }
).execute();
```

Or adding retry into a [SQL Batch](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-batch.html#optimistic-transaction):

```
begin
let upd = UPDATE #1010:2651 SET name='foo'
commit retry 100
return $upd
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I set execution mode as "synchronous", things get even worse. My vertices are always out of date and are never in a state to be updated.
I'm using Pyorient with rabbitMQ as a messaging service. So rabbitMQ will keep trying to write the record until it succeed. The problem is that the record never gets released. The only way to release the lock is to restart the OrientDB.

Comment: The problem may be in pyorient or rabbitmq.

Comment: I seems like a combination of things were playing havoc on my servers. I got a memory leak on pyorient and that was slowing my dockers down to the point of hardly responding. This probably prevent the connection form closing properly. I'm not sure if that was the reason but setting execution mode as "synchronous" suddenly worked. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm still confused by the documentation. "..., in order to reduce the impact of the latency in the replication, the suggested configuration is to set executionMode to "asynchronous".

I understood that "asynchronous" was prefered on distributed servers? It doesn't seem to work well in "asynchronous" at all! Not if the DB locks up like that. Even after I kill the connection.

Comment: It's only if you don't have multiple data centers, but just a network with high latency, in order to reduce the impact of the latency in the replication.

Comment: I just tested it. Even if I don't use pyorient and only update records through the GUI, at times, some records still lock up if the "executionMode" is set to "synchronous". It happens randomly. I don't think running in "asynchronous" is an option at all.

Comment: @anber could you please help us to reproduce the problem? Asynch replication should free locks soon or later, so it looks like a bug.

Comment: I will try and find a way to reproduce it. My setup is on AWS so I will have to find a way to reproducing it locally.